# How to expose sql query (with joins on multiple table) or stored procedure as webservice

Tags: web-services, apache-tomee

I am a novice on webservices front, so please bear with me. I have developed a JavaFX desktop application connecting to database using standard JDBC way. Now that, I want to make this web application, the jdbc had to go out.

I am now implementing with tomee in between and created restful apis (created entity classes for tables and restful apis on top of it) for db access. However, I am not sure how to do this where

a) I need to execute a stored procedure
b) Where the sql query is a join on multiple tables
c) Where I need to insert a sequence in one of the columns.

Any help is appreciated, esp wrt (a) and (b).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a no-frills way of doing it, I'd use Dropwizzard (http://www.dropwizard.io).

If you want more customization, build the stack using JAX-RS, Bean Validation, an EJB as a DAO, and a couple of JPA objects to represent your tables.

See examples here:

- http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-rest/README.html
- http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-stateless/README.html
- http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-entitymanager/README.html